# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'

Tags: php, database

I am trying to send the request to API with the following code

```
  <?php
require 'connect.php';
$posts = mysqli_query($connect, query:"SELECT * FROM `api`");
print_r($posts);
 ?>
```

but it throws me

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\API\index.php on line 3

Comment: Have a look at the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) as to how you are supposed to pass the parameters.

Comment: PHP doesn't have named parameters, only positional. Just use `mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM \`api\`");` (and make the same changes in your connect.php if required.